# PowerShell Property Value Assignment

Tags: .net, powershell

Why does this not work?

```
PS deployables:\> $host.ui.rawui.windowsize.width
170
PS deployables:\> $host.ui.rawui.windowsize.width = 100
PS deployables:\> $host.ui.rawui.windowsize.width
170
```

But this does?

```
PS deployables:\> $host.ui.rawui.windowsize.width
170
PS deployables:\> $newsize = $host.ui.rawui.windowsize
PS deployables:\> $newsize.width = 100
PS deployables:\> $host.ui.rawui.windowsize = $newsize
PS deployables:\> $host.ui.rawui.windowsize.width
100
```

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding PowerShell or .NET property assignment, could someone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, I can't believe PowerShell defined setters on these structs.  Structs in .NET should generally be immutable to avoid confusion like you're seeing above.  See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil) for more details.  Structs are passed around by value.  When you modify the WindowSize struct, you are modifying a copy of it.  When you assign the whole struct e.g. using `$newsize` it works because you're assigning a whole new struct value to the WindowSize property.